# Bitmap to Array on Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe7

I'm writing procedure that rewrites bitmap to array on XE7. I wrote this piece of code:

```
PROCEDURE BitmapToArray(var inBitmap : TBitMap;
                      var outArray : TIntegerDynArray_2D);
var
x   : integer;
y   : integer;

P   : PByteArray;
begin
 SetLength(outArray,0,0);
 SetLength(outArray, inBitmap.Height, inBitmap.Width);
 for y := 0 to inBitmap.Height-1 do
  begin
    P := inBitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to inBitmap.Width-1 do
      begin
      outArray[y,x]:=P[x];
      end;
   end;

end;
```

But it doesn't work, array is filled with zeros.

Bitmap:

[image: 1]

Comment: What pixel format is your bitmap?

Comment: Hard to imagine what you say being true. Every single element is set to 0?

Comment: Yes, i get 128x128 matrix filled with 0 on Watch List. Algorithm looks fine?

Comment: Can you put the bmp on a file sharing site

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!zR8B2QiQ!x36v68LBV8Q87JQ0fh8a3L6iPcRLRasbI2mA8ACZoDU

Comment: I've recompiled the code and It's better, it scans .bmp but return inverse values of pixels 0 - white, 255-black.

Comment: You have to update the question to include all of that information. Note the current form of my answer.

Comment: You need to supply a colortable if you image is in indexed color mode. And why the lord you use low level `.Scanline[]` instead of high level `.Canvas.Pixels[]`?

Comment: @Free For perf reasons

Comment: @FreeConsulting: because looping through `Canvas.Pixels[]` is **SSLLOOWW** compared to looping through `Scanline[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said:

> I've recompiled the code and It's better, it scans .bmp but return inverse values of pixels 0 - white, 255-black.

That's because an 8bpp bitmap uses a palette to identify colours. And in your palette, `0` identifies white, and `255` identifies black. That much can be deduced from the evidence that you present. However, it is also evident when you inspect the colour table in the .bmp file.

A palette is a table of colours. The table has 256 entries. Each pixel in the bitmap is an index into the table.

If you want to get the RGB colour for each pixel, you need to read the palette color table first, and then use the `Scanline` values as indexes into that table.

Comment: I want to get only pixels intensity. How to set to monochrome bitmap that I load to TImage?

Comment: I answered the question that you asked. Then I answered the next one. And indeed note, that the question text still doesn't match my answer. I've actually answered your second question which was asked in a comment. Now you have another question. This is unfair of you. You are meant to ask one question at a time. Anyway, it seems that I am not helping you, you are not finding what I write helpful, so should I stop?